# error_message partial getting a NameError: undefined local variable or method `object'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I've researched this error but I'm not able to resolve this issue.

Here is `_micropost_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: " Caption..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Here is `_error_messages.html.erb`

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is `microposts_controller`

```
def new
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
  @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Comment: What is `.object `?  Please show your schema/migration for `Micropost` model.

Comment: Share you `error_messages` partial, shouldn't that be `f.errors`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `object'

You can render a *partial* in two ways, `render` and `render partial:`. But when you are using `partial:`, you need to send the *variables* in the `locals:` hash. So this won't work

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

It should be

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: {object: f.object} %>
```

Or without the `partial:` key

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. I was following another post about partial: that didn't include the locals: hash.

Answer (score 0):

A couple thoughts:

Does `f.object` have a value?

Also - try something like this for passing `object` to the partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', :locals => {:object => f.object} %>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can change your code below

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

into

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

I hope this help you.